# RegEx Issue matching previous and after search word

Tags: c#, regex

I have a sentence like this :

```
string wordtoFind = "try";
string test = "this try that, but it can have multiple try in that";
```

I have tried 2 RegExp found on similar question but I have an issue using them. The RegEx Should get me the word I need to find (in this case try but it can be other words) and get the word before and after him (leave a blank or empty if no word like at the start of a sentence or at the end).

try 1 :

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(test, @"(?:\\S+\\s)?\\S*"+wordtoFind+"\\S*(?:\\s\\S+)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but matches return empty

try 2 :

```
string pattern = @"(?<before>\w+)" + wordtoFind + "(?<after>\\w+)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(test, pattern);

for (int z = 0; z < matches.Count; z++)
{
     string error = matches[i].Groups["before"].ToString() + "-" + RetourLabelSansDot + "-" + matches[i].Groups["after"].ToString();
}
```

return empty as well, I had to double some `\` because it was throwing me an error. For me RegEx are like magic and I don't really get how to custom them. Is there ans issue with my regEx or do I use it wrongly ?

This is in C#,

Comment: Don't use \\ in your regex when it's present inside verbatim..

Comment: @AvinashRaj the fact is that if i dont double the \ C# compiler throw me an error

Comment: @Slayner He means the strings with the @ before them.  Those are verbatim and do not require you to escape backslashes.

Comment: @juharr Ok, so i would just have needed to add another @ before the seconde part of the regEx to prevent the compiler from throwing an error

Comment: Can the word to find potentially be contained within a hyphenated compound adjective (e.g. "the" in "state-of-the-art")?  And if so, how should it be handled?

Comment: @ClayVerValen I think you should post another question for this, because it's not exactly the same, so I don't know if people can answer in this one.

Comment: @Slayner - You are the only one that can answer this as it relates to unstated requirements of your OP that could impact whether an answer will work for you.

Comment: @ClayVerValen Ho I though you were the one asking for this question. In my case yes it can happen I guess, i don't really know for now it's not part of what were told to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct code:

```
string wordtoFind = "try";
string test = "this try that, but it can have multiple try in that";
string pattern = @"(?:^\W*|(?<before>\w+)\W+)" + Regex.Escape(wordtoFind) + @"(?:\W+(?<after>\w+)|\W*$)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(test, pattern);

for (int z = 0; z < matches.Count; z++)
{
     string error = matches[z].Groups["before"].ToString() + "-" +wordtoFind + "-" + matches[z].Groups["after"].ToString();
     Console.WriteLine(error);
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/3RNIN9)

The pattern is built dynamically, thus, the keyword must be `Regex.Escape`d. Then, the word that is matched with `\w+` must be followed with non-word symbols to match a whole `wordToFind`, thus, you need to add `\W+`. **Alternatives `^\W*` and `\W*$` will make sure the matches are found in edge cases.**

And a note on verbatim string literals: it is easier to define regex patterns with them as they allow using single backslashes with regex meta classes  (like `\w`, `\s`, etc.)

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

- `^\W*` - matches at the start of string followed by zero or more non-word characters,
- `|` or....
- `(?<before>\w+)` - Named capture group (the value to be obtained via `Match.Groups["before"].Value`) that matches 1 or more characters that are either letters, or digits, or `_`.
- `\W+` - one or more characters that are not word characters (not letters, or digits, or `_`).
- `Regex.Escape(wordtoFind)` - your keyword (literal)
- `\W+` - see above
- `(?<after>\w+)` - Named capture group (the value to be obtained via `Match.Groups["after"].Value`) see above
- `|` - or...
- `\W*$` - zero or more non-word characters before the end of string.

Comment: so i can't concat the string like i did, I just needed the Regex.Escape Oo.

Comment: If you are using C#6, you can use interpolated strings :) Like `$@"(?<before>\w+)\W+{Regex.Escape(wordtoFind)}\W+(?<after>\w+)"`, I guess.

Comment: can I had to this RegEx \b arount the "+Regex.Escape(wordtoFind)+" so it can't return to my thing like tryhard ? or does the regEx will need aother construction ?

Comment: It won't return `tryhard` because `\W+` matches 1 or more non-word characters forcing the keyword to be a whole word. Just check the IDEONE demo. I added that case to the test string.

Comment: I check It but wanted to make sur of something, i'd like to understand it instead of just coping it, so it will match for any case where try got space, dot, or else like this. But what will happen if the sentence is " this, try, that" ? Does the "," will be in the result ?

Comment: `\W+` is not enclosed in `(...)`, so it will just be matched, not *captured*, thus, you won't have it in the *after* or *before* groups. I added the regex explanation.

Comment: Okay thanks for the full explanation, really nice of you.

Comment: If you still have doubts, please feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: It will be find for now, i'm going to try on my own before requesting help if I got issue.But i'll keep that in mind.

Comment: well after several try I have a question, if the sentence is "try that,..." so the before and after could be blank it actually return nothing to me ? is this because if no all condition match then nothing is returned ?

Comment: Right, I added support for edge cases

Answer (score 2):

Your second regex is correct, it returns empty since you don't have any word char exists before and after `try`.

Comment: So it take the space into account like they were word ?

Comment: So in the case of the seconde regEx it will have return some only in the case of the word where xxtryzz ?

Comment: okay, sorry i'm really a newbie concerning regex so i don't get all about that, but i'm learning little by little (btw nice link on your profil, i'm going to check them for C# :) )

Comment: it's ok.. You won't forget the lesson if it's learned from mistakes... :-)